# How to get a instance of db from node-mongo native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

Consider, I have MongoDB connection opened in the main `app.js` file itself and the following code fall in it's call back:

```
mongodb.connect('MongoDBUrlGoesHere', function (err, db) {
   app.listen(app.get('port'), function AppListnCB() {
       console.log("Server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
   });
});
```

This is all done to have only one db instance across the application.

Now, If we are in another `external.js` file and need a same `db` object which is aleady has connected. This can be done very easily if we are using [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) or [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)

Can someone help me to find how this can be done with native driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a wrapper, a new module where you store the db instance, something similar to this:

```
//db.js
var HOSTNAME = ...
var PORT = ...

var db = module.exports = {};
var instance;

db.connect = function (){
    ...
    instance = <db_instance>;
};

db.disconnect = function (){
    ...
    instance = null;
};

db.instance = function (){
    return instance;
};
```

Now, every time you need the db instance retrieve it by doing:

```
var db = require ("./path/to/db");
db.instance ();
```