# How to export an object that only becomes available in an async callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a db.js file in which I set up a MongoDB connection. I would like to export the database object into my main app.js file:

```
// db.js
require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, function (err, db) {
    module.exports = db;
});

// app.js
var db = require('./db');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection(/* … */); // throws error
});
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'collection'

So, how can I export the `db` object properly?

Comment: How about exporting like `exports=require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect;`. Then execute the request, and do whatever inside the callback?

Comment: On first glance it seems it should work. What do you see if you do console.log(db) after var db=require('./db') and inside the app.get callback? And did you try a console.log(db) inside the db.js connect callback?

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @JanMisker The first two console.log statements (both in app.js) return `{}`. However, inside the connect callback, the correct object is logged (the log is very long).

Comment: The call to `connect` is asynchronous, yet the `require` of the `db.js` file is synchronous. So, it would never be set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse mongodb connection in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647779/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

The best option, as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939452/how-to-export-an-object-that-only-becomes-available-in-an-async-callback/20939539#comment31446168_20939539) by [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs), is to export a promise:

```
// database.js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Q = require('q'),
    connect = Q.nbind(MongoClient.connect, MongoClient);

var promise = connect(/* url */);        

module.exports = {
  connect: function () {
    return promise;
  }
}

// app.js
var database = require('./database');

database.connect()
  .then(function (db) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      db.collection(/* … */);
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error connecting to DB:', err);
  })
  .done();
```

(I'm using awesome [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library here.)

---

Below's the old version of my answer, left for the sake of history (but if you don't want to use promises, instead of going that road, you should use [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939670/458193)).

Its downside is that it will open a connection each time you `require('database.js)` (bummer!)

```
// DO NOT USE: left for the sake of history

// database.js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function connect(cb) {
  MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, cb);
}

module.exports = {
  connect: connect
}

// app.js
var database = require('./database');

database.connect(function (err, db) {
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      db.collection(/* … */);
  });
});
```

Comment: In this case, he has to open the connection in every file, right?

Comment: I guess, or maybe export a promise, then chain?

Comment: @elclanrs mmm... Something of that sort. This is an interesting question.

Comment: Nice one. Haven't used MongoDb but I would go with the promise.

Comment: +1 for promises, you might want to show how to handle the `err` case as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it as you want to do it, because, quoting [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports):

> Note that assignment to `module.exports` must be done immediately. It cannot be done in any callbacks.

Instead however, you can assign a *property* of `module.exports` in a callback, therefore this will work;

```
// db.js
require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, function (err, db) {
    module.exports.instance = db;
});

// app.js
var db = require('./db');

// some time later (when `.instance` is available)
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.instance.collection(/* … */);
});
```

However, the *some time later* is a bit of a pain, so you may just want to use some sort of callback;

```
// db.js
var queue = [];
var instance = null;

require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, function (err, db) {
    instance = db;

    while (queue.length) {
        queue.pop()(instance);
    }
});

module.exports.done = function (callback) {
    if (instance === null) {
        queue.push(callback);
    } else {
        callback(instance);
    }
};

// app.js
require('./db').done(function (db) { 
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        db.collection(/* … */);
    });
});
```

The above also handles cases where handlers via `done()` are attached *after* the connection has already been made.

Comment: +1, you might want to show how to handle the `err` case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The servers typically have 3 phases: init, serve and uninit. This seems obvious but when you start writing servers from scratch (ie. in Java you start inheriting from HttpServlet) sometimes you forget how to do the things...

In the startup phase you must open the db connection (pool) and save the object somewhere (typically in your `db.js` module). Then in the service phase retrieve the mongodb connection from `db.js`.

Related: [How to get a instance of db from node-mongo native driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248900/how-to-get-a-instance-of-db-from-node-mongo-native-driver/17249913#17249913)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
// db.js
require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, function (err, db) {
    module.exports = db;
});

// app.js
var db = require('./db');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection(/* … */); // throws error
});
```

You've called `connect` in the `db.js` class, yet it's asynchronous.

The call in `app.js` to `require` is synchronous in behavior though, so it will always receive an undefined value (as the `exports` will not be assigned to a value at the time the `db.js` has finished executing).

I'd suggest keeping things simple.

The option I usually use is something where the app code makes the connection and doesn't start listening for HTTP connections until it is complete. Then, I'll initialize each `route` file by calling a named method and pass the database connection to it.

Or, you could just always call connect in each module, yet cache the value. (The connect call would need to be called within the route callback code so that the routes were defined immediately and not when the connection was actually established).

```
// db.js
var _db = null;
exports = function(callback) {
    if (!_db) {
        _db = {};   // only one connection, so we'll stop others from trying
        require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(/* the URL */, function (err, db) {
            _db = db;
            callback(err, db);
        });
    } else {
        callback(null, _db);
    } 
};

// app.js

var db = require('./db');
db(function(err, connection) {
  // store the connection value here and pass around, or ...
  // call this always in each file ...
});
/// or ...

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db(function(err, connection) {
       connection.collection(/* … */); 
    });
});
```

Or, you could use MongooseJS (a wrapper for the native NodeJS MongoDB driver) where commands, etc. are queued if the connection isn't available yet ....